# why malloc does not work without casting?

Tags: c, malloc

please consider the following code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}
```

the curious line is

```
struct Person *who = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

I searched internet a bit for malloc() usages. about half of them are written with casting, others are not. on vs2010, without `(struct Person*)` cast an error emerges:

```
1>c:\users\juhyunlove\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\learnc\struct\struct\struct.cpp(19): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Person *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

So what is a proper way to create a pointer and assign memory to it?

Comment: If you write C code, you should **always** compile it as C and you **must never** cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Rename `struct.cpp` to `struct.c` to make Visual Studio unearth its incredibly outdated C compiler.

Comment: BTW, don't `assert` the return value of `malloc`. Check its return value proper with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you are using a C++ compiler.

Casting `malloc` (assuming the type is not `void *`) is required in C++. In C, it is not required and  it is even recommended to not cast `malloc`.

In C there is an implicit conversion from `void *` to all object pointer types during assignment.

```
void *p = NULL;
int *q = p;  // valid in C, invalid in C++
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your file from struct.cpp, to struct.c, the compiler will do what you expect a C compiler to do, rather than do what a C++ compiler should do (as explained above). Visual Studio comes with a compiler that can do both C and C++, so it's just a case of naming the file correctly when you create it.

I'm not sure if renaming the file inside visual studio is enough, or if you have to add a new file called struct.c, copy the content from the existing file into it, and then delete teh original struct.cpp. The latter definitely works.